# Why does nginx default to my proxypass?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a proxy server to serve two web apps on a single server that are running on separate ports (for local development purposes).  Below is the full nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json  application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    server {
      server_name news.mysite;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
      }
    }

    server {
      server_name blog.mysite;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
      }
    }

#   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

When accessing the subdomains from the browser I see the expected content based on the web apps that are running.  However, when I access the main domain through the browser (http://mysite), it displays the content from  the first proxypass (news.mysite @ localhost:3001).  I would have expected one of the following two scenarios:

- Serve content from the default directory @ /var/www/html
- The typical "This site can’t be reached" error in the browser.

Why is nginx proxying the first proxypass it finds by default and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `server` that nginx encounters for a socket will be considered the default unless you create another one that you explicitly mark as the default.

So for your case, you would want to add an additional `server` block as a catch all:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
}
```